# Yesod redirect to anchor on page

Tags: haskell, yesod

Is it possible to redirect to `example.com/page#anchor` using `redirect` and Yesod's routing system?  If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `getUrlRender` to get the URL renderer, and then append `#anchor` to that. For example:

```
render <- getUrlRender
redirect $ render myRoute <> "#anchor"
```

It might be worth adding a convenience function to automate this process.

Comment: I end up with a type error for Text and [a0] because of the ++.  How can I rectify this?  I do have OverloadedStrings enabled.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to `++` from classy-prelude. Use `<>` from `Data.Monoid` for the same effect.