# Redirecting in Yesod to Routes with Arguments

Tags: haskell, yesod

Assume I have a route

```
/argument/#Int ArgumentR GET POST
```

and the corresponding handlers

```
getArgumentR :: Int -> Handler Html
getArgumentR x = undefined

postArgument :: Int -> Handler Html
postArgument x = do
    ...
    redirect (??)
```

where, after running a form, I want to redirect from the post to the get Handler (for the same `x`). How can I turn `ArgumentR` into an excepted Route, i.e. apply the argument `x` to `ArgumentR`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yesod redirect to anchor on page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20886254/yesod-redirect-to-anchor-on-page)

Comment: I do not think this answers the question. I saw that new versiond of `Yesod` supply a `.#.` function for that, but `ArgumentR .#. x` renders to `/argument#x` not `/argument/x` (and also does not type check).

Comment: Ah, the problem is with argument. Doesn't `redirect $ ArgumentR x` work, then?

Comment: No, does not type check. I also tried various other versions (of brackets, mapping via fmap,...). Unfortunately I could also not find any documentation on this use case.

Comment: Post error message, please.

Comment: Trying to reproduce the error in this minimal example failed, your answer is correct, it didn't work for me for unrelated reasons. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes like `ArgumentR` listed in `routes` file are simple data constructors. The number of arguments they take equals to the number of #-pieces in its declaration. So, in your case you need

```
redirect (ArgumentR x)
```